# Read csv in python pandas with different number of quotation marks and commas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

my csv-data-file is looking like this:

```
"Date,""Time"",""Tags"",""Measurement"",""Info"",""GMT+01:00""";
"13.11.2022,""21:47:56"","""",""156"","""",""GMT+01:00""";
"29.05.2022,""09:00:00"","""",""Comment1,Comment2"","""",""GMT+01:00""";
```

The line begins with double quotation marks and ends with double quotation marks and a semicolon.
The first column has no quotation marks and all the other entries have two of them.

> The separator is a comma, but there can also be comments instead of values in a row which are also separated by a comma. Some columns have no data ("""").

How can I read this file in python pandas?

I tried different codes, i. e.:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', lineterminator=';', quotechar='"')
```

I get errors like (test.csv):

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 7
```

or (real.csv)

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 26 fields in line 147, saw 27
```

It seems as the comma in between the two quotation marks is also recognized as a separator.

Thanks,
regards
sts85

Comment: The rows have different number of columns; hence, you cannot parse it since it is ambiguous which value belongs to what column.

Comment: My fault. I messed it up by creating a minimal example.
Now it is corrected, but the error remains almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = [line[1:-3].replace('""', '"') + '\n' for line in f]
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(data)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```